# A Problem on Time Complexity of Algorithms

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete, open-problem

I want no know if the following problem is solved or not, or how can I solve it?

Problem: For every integer $t$, Is there any problem that can be verified in $O(n^{s})$ but its solution can be found in $T(n)=\omega(n^{st})$, i.e., its solution can not be found in $O(n^{st})$.

By verifying, I mean that given a candidate solution $y$, we can judge whether $y$ is correct or not in time $O(n^s)$.

Comment: I asked a similar question, but what I asked was compeletely wrong. So I asked the correct version here and deleted the previous one.

Comment: Is there anyway I can migrate this question to cs.stackexchange.com? or I should ask it again?

Comment: Imho this is a poorly stated question. Or is it just me?

Comment: Obviously, an integer s is desired (s > 0)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to know is covered by the answers to [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/nondeterministic-linear-time-vs-the-deterministic-time-hierarchy) and [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1079/ntimenk-dtimenk) on cstheory stackexchange.

It seems that the answer is likely to be yes, since it follows from $\mathbf{P} \neq \mathbf{NP}$ by a padding argument, but it isn't currently proven.

To elaborate, if I am understanding things correctly what you asking about is this statement:

For all $t$ and all $s$, there is a problem in $\mathbf{NTIME}(n^s)$ that is not in $\mathbf{TIME}(n^{s t})$.

There is a slight subtlety that you may be asking about search problems, but this is about decision problems, but I think that shouldn't matter.

According to the links, we don't even know that $\mathbf{NTIME}(n^s) \neq \mathbf{TIME}(n^s)$ so we couldn't even prove the weaker statement of finding a lower bounded of, say, $n^{s + 1}$, let alone a lower bound of $n ^{s t}$ (for $t>1$).

In other words, if we can't even manage to prove the much weaker statement that $\mathbf{NTIME}(n^s) \neq \mathbf{TIME}(n^s)$, we don't have much hope of proving the much harder statement that $\mathbf{NTIME}(n^s) \not \subseteq \mathbf{TIME}(n^{st})$. You can be fairly sure therefore that it is an open problem.

I also clamied that the statement follows from $\mathbf{P} \neq \mathbf{NP}$. To prove this, we shall assume that the statement fails and use it to prove $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{NP}$.

If the statement is false, then in particular there is some $t$ and $s$ such that $\mathbf{NTIME}(n^s) \subseteq \mathbf{TIME}(n^{st})$. Let $f$ be a function that has a nonderministic algorithm that runs in polynomial time.

Let $p$ be a padding function, that concatenates the string $11\ldots110$ to its input so that $f(n)$ terminates in less than $|p(n)|$ steps. Then there is a linear time nondeterministic algorithm for $f'$ such that $f'(p(n)) = f(n)$ and $f'(m) = 0$ if there is no $n$ such that $m = p(n)$ (essentially the same algorithm as for $f$ but it is now linear time because the input is longer).

Since $f'(m) \in \mathbf{NTIME}(m)$ we know by assumption that $f'(m) \in \mathbf{TIME}(m^{st})$. So $f'$ has a *deterministic* algorithm that runs in polynomial time. By composing $f'$ with $p$, we also get a deterministic polynomial time algorithm for $f$, showing that $\mathbf{NP} \subseteq P$.

Comment: I could not find my answer in those links. Could you please explain where exactly I can find it? Thanks

Comment: I'll add an edit and hopefully explain how it follows.

Comment: But this is not a proof. You just reduced it to the P=NP problem, that is at least as hard as this problem.

Comment: Hopefully, this is clearer in the edit, but what I am saying is that it is likely to be true because it follows from $P \neq NP$, but it *isn't currently proven*, so no this isn't a proof!

Answer (score -1):

You have an array of $n^{st}$ integers and want to check if there is a zero. You check it in $O(1)$, if the index is given. You find it just by the brute-force search in $O(n^{st})$.

Comment: $O(1)$-access to elements (random access on the tape of a TM) is not part of the standard computational model, though.

Comment: TM is equivalent to the RAM. I formulated the common idea. Suppose you have just $n^s$ numbers, but are looking for some subarray of $t$ elements, which can be found just by the bruteforce. Then the bruteforce will be $\Theta(n^{st})$ and checking, using indices, $\Theta(n^s)$

Comment: I might be missing something in your definition of the problem; where does the $\Theta(n^{st})$ come from? I would have gone with $O(tn^s)$ (scanning the array $t$ times)

Comment: This is the same, in fact, but anyway. You know $t$ before you launch the TM, so you can create $t$ additional states for TM and scan array one time.

Comment: What do you mean, "it is the same"? Clearly, $\Theta(n^{st})\neq O(n^{s})$.

Comment: As I said, $t$ is the constant in your algo, so if you multiply on it, it doesn't really matter. I am saying about $O(tn^s)$, not $O(n^{ts})$ :)

Comment: Yes, but you wrote "Then the bruteforce will be $\Theta(n^{st})$.". This is the thing I am questioning.

Comment: Yep, the number of possible subsrrays is Θ($n^{st}$). And you should iterate them all with appropriate problem. (the elements of subarray should be dependent for sure, otherwise you are right, Θ($tn^s$) would be enough)

Comment: For example, you have $n^{s}$ integers and want to find $t$ such that sum of them is $S$ and the sum of their exponents is equal to $E$. This is the subset-sum problem with additional restrictions, the single way to solve such problem is the brute-force with some heuristics, $O(n^{st})$ in a common case. But the checking is still $O(n^{s})$